# Cant get view to render

Tags: node.js, express, couchdb, couchdb-nano

I am developing an application with node.js, express, couchDB and using nano to communicate with couch.
I am using a jquery get request from client javascript. Using fiddler i can see that i get my view in the RAW result but the view is never rendered.

client:

```
$.get('employee/'+customerId, function(data){
        return;
    });
```

route:

```
app.get('/employee/:id', employee.viewEmployee);
```

viewEmployee:

```
exports.viewEmployee = function(req, res){
    db.get(req.params['id'], { revs_info: false }, function(err, body, header) {
        res.render('employee/single', {employee: body});
    });
};
```

Everything works with no errors and i get the 'employee/single' view html in the raw response. my question is why the view is not rendered? why is the html just sent back in the raw and how can i get this to work?

Comment: I replaced the jquery get with: window.location = '/employee/'+customerId; and it now works, but i still cant wrap my head around why the get doesnt do the job

Answer (score 2):

Your $.get call is using a call back that isn't doing any thing.

from the [jQuery api examples](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

```
$.get("test.php",
   function(data){
     $('body').append( "Name: " + data.name ) // John
              .append( "Time: " + data.time ); //  2pm
   }, "json");
```

Shows you how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an ajax call.

try console.log(data) inside your $.get callback, are you seeing the html  you expect?

Comment: yes have get the html i expect but the jade view i have created is not rendered. I have continued with using window.location instead of the $.get and the application is behaving as expected now.

Comment: use type: 'html' in your ajax call.